# Could not connect to linux VM in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

How do I connect to a linux box in microsoft azure portal. The "connect" link is disabled.
It says you can not connect as it is not a windows server.
But there is no way I could connect to the newly created vm nor there is a suggestion.

Comment: See [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-quick-create-cli/) for how to create and connect to a Linux VM in Azure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot directly remote desktop to Linux VM in Azure. Only the servers with GUI can be connected using connect button. You might need to enable GUI in your Linux VM first to enable connect button.

To connect to newly created Linux VM use SSH.

For Windows use - http://www.putty.org/

For Linux and Mac - Open terminal and enter command ssh ip-address

For example ssh 52.1.3.102

**Edit :**

Enabling GUI in Linux : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-classic-remote-desktop/

Comment: How do I enable GUI in your Linux VM first to enable connect button ?

Comment: Connect to the server using SSH and then install GUI.